# Java Trouble with loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

This is quite difficult to explain but the basic idea is that we have 2 ArrayLists. You compare List 1 to List 2 and if the entries match then you print Array List +1, and if not you just return the element from Array List 1. The comparison works fine, but the problem comes to printing out the results. My original design prints off both the translation and the original word when I only want one or the other. This is the original design :

```
public void compareLists(){
    String nameSearch;

    for(PirateDictionary w: words){

        nameSearch = w.toString();
        Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Phrase c = it.next();
            if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                System.out.println( it.next().toString());

            }

        }

        System.out.println(w.toString());
    }

}
```

Below is a different attempt, I'm pretty sure that this one is closer because you want to do either one or the other and the first design always includes both so I think that a loop has to be used here, but I don't exactly know how to implement it.

```
for(PirateDictionary w: words){

        nameSearch = w.toString();
        Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();
        Phrase c = it.next();
        if(w.toString().equals(c.getName())){

            while(it.hasNext())
            {

                if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                    System.out.println( it.next().toString());

                }

            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(w.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to print one or the other for every element in your iterator?

Comment: If List 1 and List 2 match then I want it to print List 2 +1 so lets say that woman from list 1 matches woman from list 2, you would then want to print woman +1 which is 'lass'. Currently I can only get it to print both woman and lass when I only just want the translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
 for(PirateDictionary w: words){

    nameSearch = w.toString();
    Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();
    boolean found = false;

    while(it.hasNext() && !found) {

       Phrase c = it.next();

       if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
           System.out.println( c.getName());
           found = true;
       }
    }

    if (!found)
        System.out.println(w.toString());
}
```

We use a `boolean` to remember if we found a match, and if we didn't we just print out the normal word. Also be careful that you don't use `it.next()` twice, because you will skip one element then!

Comment: Brilliant, a simple flag gets the job done, thank you very much